# How to exclude certain file types or paths from recently used files (“Recent”)?

Tags: files, 20.10

In order not to clutter the list of my recently used files, e. g. when looking through a bunch of media files, I’d like to exclude some file types or paths from being included in the file history (e. g. exclude all `.jpg` files, or, if that’s not possible, at least exclude individual paths like `~/Pictures` or `~/Music` to have a similar effect).

I know that the list of recently used files is stored in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`, but how can I configure what is written there? The only relevant option seems to be in “Settings → Privacy → File History & Trash”, where file history can be disabled entirely. However, I still want to have a file history, just with some more configuration. I remember that, for example, in the Unity days, it was possible to exclude certain file types (like “Images”, “Videos” or “Documents”) from being tracked in this way – did this functionality disappear?

Comment: As far as I know, it's individual applications that write to `recently-used.xbel`.  If that's the case, you'd probably have to review source code of each application to find out if it's even configurable.

Comment: @Nmath Well, as I said, this used to be possible in Unity, so I was hoping that there is some common interface or configuration that enabled this functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can boot up a live session of a version of Ubuntu where it worked in the past.  You might be able to deduce how it worked in the past.